# single vs multiple ad units and match rate in admob

Tags: android, admob, ads

So, I have one interstitial ad unit which is used in all screens/activities in my app, but the match rate is too low 12% only. So, is it a good idea to create each interstitial ad unit per screen ? So that the ad requests will be divided to multiple ad units and it will improve match rate and so the revenue? What's your thoughts guys?

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not work that way. Please check if you have any Ad Serving Limit on your account. If you have any than you will have to wait for the required time.

On the other hand if you don't have any limit on your account then please check the ad units, whether you have made some changes to its settings like, media type, frequency capping, bid etc. Also you can check the Blocking Tab, like whether the categories or advertisers have been blocked by you. This could be the possible reasons for the low match rate/fill rate.